# Error in quantile.default(x, p = p) in EgdeR calcNormFactors

Tags: edger, tmm

I am trying to run `TMM` normalization using `rpy2` and when I run `calcNormFactors()` function:

```
dge_list = edgeRLib.DGEList(counts=rawcounts)
dge_list = edgeRLib.calcNormFactors(dge_list, method="TMM")
```

I am getting the error:

> RRuntimeError: Error in quantile.default(x, p = p) : 
>     missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

So, I thought that maybe my `rawcounts` `2D` `numpy` array contains `nan` values but it does not. I checked it with both `pd.isnull()` and `np.isnan()` functions. So, I suspect now that the `2D` array itself can not be normalized for some reason and I do not know why. The error is most probably not related to `rpy2` set up and `R` installation because it was working before for similar `numpy` arrays but failed this time. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, it turned out that some rows and/or columns contained all values as zeros and that was the reason for the error. I wrote a function to fix that:

```
def fix_rawcounts(rawcounts, cell_ids, gene_symbols):
    '''The function checks whether there are 
    any rows or columns with all zeros 
    and removes them'''
    print('Checking whether rows or columns contain all zeros')

    # Checking columns
    count_arr = np.apply_along_axis(np.count_nonzero, axis=0, arr=rawcounts )
    rawcounts = rawcounts[:,count_arr != 0]

    # Checking rows
    count_arr = np.apply_along_axis(np.count_nonzero, axis=1, arr=rawcounts )
    rawcounts = rawcounts[count_arr != 0,:]

    print('finished checking zero rows and columns')
    return rawcounts
```